# How to get global keyboard input in UWP app without using CoreWindow.KeyDown

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, monogame

Since CoreWindow.KeyDown is broken in the latest few builds (6 months) of windows 10 I need an alternative way to get keyboard input. There are 3 ways of getting mouse input that I know of but I cannot find any alternative ways for keyboard input.

Are there any other methods for keyboard input in a UWP program? If so, what are they?

The issue is that CoreWindow.KeyDown events can be delayed by up to 30 seconds!

Comment: Are you sure they're broken everywhere? CoreWindow.KeyDown works fine for me...

Comment: What is your OS version and your project target version? Have you tried to test your app on other device?

Comment: @grace-feng-msft

We have tried multiple computers and OS versions, it is a well known issue among the monogame and sharpdx communities.

It only breaks when you are receiving a lot of mouse events and under moderate or higher cpu load. So it effects most games. You wouldn't get it to happen in an app.

See here for more info. https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/pull/5333

It is an issue in the UWP framework, I have been yet to get someone from Microsoft to acknowledge it so it can be fixed.

The issue is that CoreWindow.KeyDown events can be delayed by up to 30 seconds!

Comment: @grace-feng-msft 

Here is a video showing the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHr91Sr_W_g and another person with the issue http://community.monogame.net/t/keyboard-input-caused-by-mouse/8203

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, there is one alternative way: `CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated`

But beware: It gives false positives e.g. when I press the Menu key (Alt) it also says that I'm pressing the Control key.
Also it makes a difference between KeyDown and SystemKeyDown (I couldn't find a definition of the difference between the two), but when trying to pair the with KeyUp and SystemKeyUp you're also in for a surprise as they do not always match. :/

Anyway, if you get it to work for you then `CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated` is the answer to your question.

Comment: SystemKey* events are triggered if there's Alt key pressed.
I'm also facing the RightAlt triggering LeftCtrl issue, and Microsoft doesn't offer any solution, which just sucks.